# AWS Cognito user pool does not send verification email when configured with Serverless framework and user signs up with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, serverless, serverless-framework

I configured Cognito user pool and client with Serverless framework as follows:

```
CognitoUserPool:
  Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
  Properties:
    MfaConfiguration: OFF
    UserPoolName: user-pool
    UsernameAttributes:
      - email
    AutoVerifiedAttributes:
      - email
    VerificationMessageTemplate:
      DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK    
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        MinimumLength: 8
        RequireLowercase: True
        RequireNumbers: True
        RequireSymbols: False
        RequireUppercase: True
CognitoUserPoolClient:
  Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient"
  Properties:
    ClientName: user-pool-client
    GenerateSecret: False
    UserPoolId:
      Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

I am able to sign user up with aws-amplify in Next.js app, however, the user is not yet confirmed. I want to get confirmation email with the link to click on, so that the user is confirmed and can log in (so far I had to confirm the user in Cognito in AWS console). However, that does not happen with this configuration.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your cloudformation template is automatically verifying the email attribute.

Try removing this block:

```yaml
AutoVerifiedAttributes:
 - email
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried removing it but it does not help. In fact, I think this is the exact line of config I would need to tell Cognito that it needs to verify the email. I still cannot figure out what is wrong.